# Trouble passing HTML Integer array to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp

Having trouble passing a JSP Integer array to javascript.  The JSP array is correctly populated.  I can correctly render elements of the JSP array in my JSP code.  However, when I pass the JSP array to my javascript function the values are undefined in my javascript code.

JSP Code Snippet

```
....

<! This works correctly !>
<div class="col content-M">
  <p>JSP Array Population Test</p>
    ${daynumbers[2]}
</div>

<! This does not work !>
<div class="col content-L">
  <p>Pass a JSP Integer Array to setDayValues</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">setDayValues(${daynumbers});</script>
  <div id="columnchart_values"></div> 
</div>

....
```

JavaScript Snippet

```
var a = Array(6);

function setDayValues(values) {
    a[0] = values[0];
    a[1] = values[1];
    a[2] = values[2];
    a[3] = values[3];
    a[4] = values[4];
    a[5] = values[5];     
}

function simpleColumnChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
         ['1', a[0], 'blue'],
         ['2', a[1], 'blue'],
         ['3', a[2], 'blue'],
         ['4', a[3], 'blue'],
         ['5', a[4], 'blue'],
         ['6', a[5], 'blue']
    ]);

  ....

}
```

Like I said, a[x] is undifined in javascript.

Comment: 1. What does `<script type="text/javascript">setDayValues(${daynumbers});</script>` look like when it arrives at the browser? 2. What errors do you see in the web console? 3. What do you see when you use the debugger built into the browser to watch what happens in `setDayValues`?

Comment: daynumbers is corrrectly populated when it arrives in the browser.  If you notice the first <div>, the value that is displayed in the browser is the correct number.  When I execute the second <div>, the values are undifined.  When I place the value in an alert(values[2]), I get nothing in the alert box.  When I do this, alert(parseInt(values[2]), I get a "NaN" in the alert box.  I presume NaN stands for "Not a Number".

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions above. The first div (the one that works) has nothing to do with `setDayNumbers`. Please see the questions above again. The most likely scenario is that the expansion of `${daynumbers}` in the script tag I called out isn't what you think it is, and in particular isn't a valid JavaScript array. If (as an example) it's output as `1, 2, 3, 4`, then that would be the problem.

Comment: I am not understanding your question.  daynumbers appears to be a valid JSP integer array.  The first div is only used to verify that daynumbers is correctly populated.  Can I directly pass a JSP integer array as a function parameter?  If I redefined the javascript function like, setDayValues(${daynumbers[0]} ${daynumbers[1]}, ${daynumbers[2]}, ...) it works correctly.  However, I have too many elements in daynumbers, to use this method.  Make sense?

Comment: Open the page in your browser. Right click and choose "View source." Find the script tag that calls `setDayNumbers` in the source that was delivered to the browser, copy it, and paste it into the question. No, of course you can't directly pass a server-side JSP integer array to a client-side JavaScript function: One is on the server, the other is on the client. But you can do what you're trying to do: Have the JSP output JavaScript code that defines a JavaScript array. It's just that `${daynumbers}` is apparently not doing that.

Comment: Ok, as requested: <script type="text/javascript">setDayValues([I@cfbdda1);</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you understand ${daynumbers} is wrong. what will ${daynumbers} return? a javascript array? try console.log(${daynumbers}), you will notice your problem, since you can see value of ${daynumbers[0]} , you probably returns a java Array Object which javascript won't understand, so you can try to convert ${daynumbers} to be a json string, and parse it.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  When I looked at the HTML source, I could see that the ${daynumbers} was an object reference.  I presume Javascript probably does not know anything about a object reference.  By the way, the first div simply shows the value of daynumbers[2] which agrees with the fact that javascript only sees the values and not the reference.  I agree with populating the function parameter with a json string and then just parse it in the javascript function.

Comment: The final solution was to create a CSV string for daynumbers. In the javacode I did, var days = new Array(), then days = daynumber.split(',').  I then converted strings to integers, days[i] = parseInt(days[i]).  All very simple.  Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `${daynumbers}` is resulting in invalid JavaScript being sent to the client.

If you want to output the array of integers, use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-):

```
<script type="text/javascript">setDayValues(${Arrays.toString(daynumbers)});</script>
```

The client browser will see

```
<script type="text/javascript">setDayValues([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]);</script>
```

...(with your actual values, of course), which is valid JavaScript defining an array with those entries.

Then in `setDayNumbers`, there's no need to copy them, just use the array passed into `setDayNumbers`:

```
function setDayNumbers(values) {
    a = values;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  The problem, like in my original code, was daynumbers is an object reference.  You can see that when I look at the page source code.  It has the object reference.  Arrays.toString could not find the reference because it knows nothing of jsp objects.

Comment: @skmansfield: And the solution, as I said in my answer, is to output that object's contents in a JavaScript-compatible way, which `Arrays.toString` does. I'm assuming `${...}` evaluates its contents as an expression (I haven't used that particular taglib).